# Testing intervalTimer from async and fakeAsync

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

The Angular Testing Guide section about [testing components with asynchronous services](https://angular.io/guide/testing#jasminedone) says that:

> Writing test functions with `done`, while more cumbersome than `async` and `fakeAsync`, is a viable and occasionally necessary technique. For example, you can't call `async` or `fakeAsync` when testing code that involves the `intervalTimer`, as is common when testing async `Observable` methods.

Does anyone know what `intervalTimer` is or why it can't be tested from `async` or `asyncFake`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `intervalTimer` is most likely in reference to `setInterval` or any other timer functionality and the reason it can't be used with `async` or `fakeAsync` is because `async` (from my understanding) usually uses the `whenStable` function on the `ComponentFixture`, and `whenStable` will never actually be called since the timer promise will never finish.  Using `fakeAsync` will actually throw an error because it tries to perform the test synchronously but when it finishes, it detects that there's still a promise yet to be resolved so it throws an error.

I got this from posting an issue on Angular's GitHub repo.  Here is the link to the issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20711

The part regarding the `whenStable` is not in that question but from researching it on my own it looks like `whenStable` and `async` are generally used together.